# Relative urls in Xampp

Tags: wordpress, url, xampp

I'm a newbie.  I've installed a copy of my main site (www.mainsite.co.uk for example) in Xampp in a folder called Wordpress and I can display it at http://localhost/wordpress/ (see attached image).  The problem is that the links all point to the main site at www.mainsite.co.uk and not the local copy.  Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the links. Means you have to change "www.mainsite.co.uk" with "localhost"/foldername.

Means if your main site link is "www.mainsite.co.uk/about". Then you have to change it with "http://localhost/wordpress/about".